# python json dump writability "not write able"

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tuples, stringio

So this is the second piece of a problem with my program, but a completely different issue, thanks to the helpful person who suggested JSON as a better method to do what I wanted....

Anyway...

some success with JSON.  The program also changed theme,  I definitely am not tying to make a game, just get the inspiration to learn more about the concept of "saving" in python..  so here's my code so far, with a valid JSON coded file to read from..  but I ran into another snag, it reports this error when I try to use the JSON 's .dump method

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 32, in <module>
File "/data/data/com.hipipal.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/python32.zip/json/__init__.py", line 177, in dump
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

Code:

```
import os
import random
import json
with open("/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts3/newgame2.txt") as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file) 
save=data
print(save)
hero=dict(save)
print(hero)
level=int(0) 
job=str("none")
experience=int(0)
strength=int(0)
intelligence=int(0)
dexterity= int(0)
health= int(0)
magic= int(0)
luck= int(0)
if hero["level"]==0:
    level=int(0)
    job=str("none")
    experience=int(0)
    strength=int(0)
    intelligence=int(0)
    dexterity= int(0)
    health= int(0)
    magic= int(0)
    luck= int(0)
    hero=[("level",level), ("job",job), ("experience",experience), ("strength",strength), ("intelligence",intelligence), ("dexterity",dexterity), ("health",health), ("magic",magic), ("luck",luck)]
    hero=dict(hero)
    with open("/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts3/newgame2.txt") as data_file:
        json.dump(hero, data_file)
```

Comment: Your code is an absolute mess, you should format it properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not opening your file in "write mode".

Try to change your `open()` line to this:

```
with open("/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts3/newgame2.txt", "w") as data_file:
    json.dump(hero, data_file)
```

By default Python's builtin [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) opens files in "read" mode.

> The most commonly-used values of mode are 'r' for reading, 'w' for
>   writing (truncating the file if it already exists), and 'a' for
>   appending (which on some Unix systems means that all writes append to
>   the end of the file regardless of the current seek position). **If mode
>   is omitted, it defaults to 'r'.** The default is to use text mode, which
>   may convert '\n' characters to a platform-specific representation on
>   writing and back on reading. Thus, when opening a binary file, you
>   should append 'b' to the mode value to open the file in binary mode,
>   which will improve portability. (Appending 'b' is useful even on
>   systems that don’t treat binary and text files differently, where it
>   serves as documentation.) See below for more possible values of mode.

Comment: Thanks James.. my cell phone really sucks at making proper formatting easy, and I'm new here... I'm sorry about all of the work it took, but thankful that the message got through..

Comment: Great to see an answer that actually brings here the useful information from a link and makes it self-contained.

Comment: Also, your solution worked like a charm, I now have a "fully functioning" save capability in my program.  I did have to format my save file specifically, which could lead to undesired accidental loss of functionality, but I am super happy with the result so far

Answer (score 1):

Change the open line to include 'w' which tells Python to open the file in write mode

```
 with open("/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts3/newgame2.txt", 'w') as data_file:
        json.dump(hero, data_file)
```

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open